# How can i get data from two different tables

Tags: java, mysql, database

Well, i have two tables in my db (MATERIALS and INVENTORY).
I have to select a material and get the details whitch are in the other table, and after that i have to show them.
I am not sure if it is ok, but i am trying with this query :

`select* from INVENTARIO whereMATRICULA IN
    (select FAMMTL_CDG_REGISTRATION from MATERIALS where
    FAMMTL_CDG_REGISTRATION = #{matricula});`

I have to put the result of this on a bean, and show it.
Is it ok?

Comment: You're missing a space here (`where MATRICULA`), but otherwise it looks okay. Why not use a JOIN instead of a sub-select? Also, are you getting an error or just asking for a SQL code review (In which case this should probably move to the codereview stack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join them using some common column(best would be ID). I guess that INVENTARIO has a foreign key to the MATERIALS. Is that correct? In that case it would be:

```
select * from INVENTARIO inv, MATERIALS mat on inv.fk = mat.id
```

Where fk is the foreign key to the MATERIALS ID. But that's just guessing since we don't know how your tables look like.
This would be an implicit "cross" join. For other possibilities see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: It  was my error, Now I have my fk to materials id. So its okay, thanks.